# "Nothing appears to happen when click on buttons" when submitting an Excel add in that will only work for a certain client. What can i do?

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

Im creating an Excel add in for a client but after submitting it for review I get feeback like:

1) Nothing appears to happen when we click on all highlighted
buttons

2) On first launch of your add-in, it is not clear what
the value proposition is.

3)  It is not clear how to configure or use the add-in, or
how the user would benefit from using the add-in.

The add in is for a specific client so it will only work with sheets with a certain format and data. What can I do to get my add-in accepted?

Comment: First step would be to make sure your add-in generates some sort of response each time the user clicks a button. For example, if the worksheet does not have the expected format or data, pop up a warning `MsgBox`. Have your client send you the workbooks on which they are attempting to run your add-in and see if you can duplicate their results, looking at things from their viewpoint. But it really sounds like you have a big disconnect with expectations between what the client wanted and what you delivered.

Answer (score 1):

If your add-in is designed to work for one specific organization only, is AppSource the most appropriate delivery mechanism for you? Have you considered the suitability of [Centralized deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment)?

If you decide that AppSource is the appropriate delivery mechanism, then the Enterprise [policies](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/office-store-validation-policy-changes-to-support-apps-and-add-ins-that-target-larger-organizations-and-enterprises/) may be of interest.

Please be aware that the validation team must be able to test the full functionality of the add-in should you wish to publish on AppSource. Please ensure that you provide full testing notes with your submission containing detailed information on the data required to test your add-in.